# Why does this PHP code take so long?

Tags: php, mysql

i wrote a little PHP Script that, should load a menu dynamically to a website. But this Script takes over about 1 second to load and i dont know what i can change.

The Database looks like this:

```
bulletID -> int not null auto_increment primary key
name -> text
top -> int
```

This is just for testing. Normally i also wouldnt use the mysql extension for connecting.
Does anyone have an idea how to speed this script up?

```
<?php
function loadMenu($startMenu, $endMenu, $startBullet, $endBullet, $bulletID) {
    error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED);
    $sql="select * from menu where top='$bulletID'";

    if($link = mysql_connect('localhost','root', '')) {

    }
    mysql_select_db('sampleDB');

    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    echo $startMenu;
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        $bulletID = $row['bulletID'];
        echo $startBullet;
        echo $row['name'];
        loadMenu($startMenu, $endMenu, $startBullet, $endBullet, $bulletID);
        echo $endBullet;
    }
    echo $endMenu;
    return TRUE;        
}

loadMenu('<ul>','</ul>','<li>','</li>', '0');
```

?>

Comment: This might be a little tough to debug since it depends on how many menu items you have, but you are essentially performing recursive SQL calls. You might just fetch the entire menu with one SQL select and then build the menu with a local data structure representing the menu (array of arrays, etc.)

Comment: u are doing recurisve calls, each time calling sql query, why not you fetch everything once, then recurisve build the list base the result